# RIP Steve Ditko, co-creator of Spider-Man and Dr. Strange

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Comics artist Steve Ditko has sadly passed away. He began work as a comic inker in 1953 alongside Joe Simon and Jack Kirby, and worked for both Marvel Comics and DC Comics before retiring from mainstream comics in 1998.

Ditko is best known for being co-creator of Marvel characters Spider-Man and Dr. Strange. Although his collaborator Stan Lee is more well-known, modern comics would not be what it is without Ditko's influence. He will truly be missed.

[image: Self-portrait of Steve Ditko, 1965]

<sub>[Self-portrait of Steve Ditko, 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ditkoselfportrait.png)</sub>

Comment: RIP Steve Ditko.

Comment: If there's any justice in the afterlife, he's now happily soaring through weird dimensions with ribbon-roads, floating islands, and giant op-art fang gateways. May his amulet never tarnish!